How do I return the correct converter?
Converter factory is not able to determine which converter to use?
I am currently working on a converter to convert components from one CMS to another CMS system.
The components in the old cms have a base class they share, specifying the name of the component - Which is also used as differentiator for the different implementation of this base class.
ex:
public abstract class ComponentBase
{
    public string? ComponentName { get; set; }
}


public class RichTextElement : ComponentBase
{
    public required string Title { get; set; }
    public required string Content { get; set; }
}

The converter I've made all inherits a BaseConverter which include a template for how I see a converter should be implemented:
public abstract class BaseConverter<T> 
{
    protected readonly ConverterTools _converterTools; ´

    protected BaseConverter(ConverterTools converterTools)
    {
        _converterTools = converterTools;
    }

    public abstract BlokComponent ConvertComponent(T component);
    public virtual IEnumerable<BlokComponent> ConvertComponents(List<T> components)
    {
        return components.Select(ConvertComponent);
    }
}

So a specific converter implementation could look like this:
public class RichTextElementConverter : BaseConverter<RichTextElement>
{
    public RichTextElementConverter(ConverterTools converterTools) : base(converterTools)
    {
    }

    private BlokTextComponent CreateText(string? title, string text)
    {
        var textComponent = new TextComponent()
        {
            Uuid = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Component = "text-v1",
            Title = title ?? string.Empty,
            Text = text),
        };

        return textComponent;

    }

    public override BlokComponent ConvertComponent(RichTextElement component)
    {
        return CreateText(component.Title, component.Content);
    }
}

Now I Need some way to deduce which converter I should use, some sort of factory that can create the converter I need.
I tried with this so far - but seem to running into problems with BaseConverter being too generic, and has to be specific?
I don't understand.
public class ConverterFactory
{
    private readonly ConverterTools _converterTools;
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<ConverterTools, BaseConverter>> _converters;

    public ConverterFactory(ConverterTools converterTools)
    {
        _converterTools = converterTools;
        _converters = new Dictionary<Type, Func<ComponentMapperContext, BaseConverter>>
        {
            { typeof(RichTextElement), context => new RichTextElementConverter(_converterTools) },
        };
    }

    public BaseConverter<T>? GetConverter<T>()
    {
        if (_converters.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var converterFactory))
        {
            return converterFactory(_converterTools) as BaseConverter<T>;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

How do let my factory return the right componentmapper, given the componentname specified in ComponentBase.
So I've constricted the baseconverter so that it looks at ComponentBase
I still have issues with the factory returning the correct converter.
My dictionary entries are all showing this error:

Cannot convert from Converters.RichTextElementConverter to Converters.BaseConverter


you need to add a constraint to T. such as where T : ComponentBase, class. In any case, I would suggest using extension methods instead. It would be easier and simpler approach. such as value.ToBlokComponent(); . This will reduce the code complexity as well (no inheritance needed).

"running into problems with BaseConverter being too generic, and has to be specific?" - be more specific. What problems? Exceptions? Compiler Errors? ...

So i've constricted the baseconverter so that it looks at ComponentBase
I still have issues with the factory retutning the correct converter.
My dictionary entries are all showing this error:
Cannot convert from Converters.RichTextElementConverter to Converters.BaseConverter<ComponentBase>  @Fildor hopes that it clarifies some stuff.

I guess RichTextElement is-a ComponentBase? Here's the deal: while those two are in a relation, BaseConverter<RichTextElement> and BaseConverter<ComponentBase> are not. The latter ones are completely unrelated types.
